# sudoers file not being used

Tags: sudo, su

In this shop root access is being handed out in a way that I'm not familiar with. See below. I have all the access I need, I was just wondering why the sudoers mechanism is not being used. I have to su to root and that by using the 
`sudo su - root` command. Nothing else works - see below. The `/etc/sudoers` file is basically empty.

```
[linuxuser@lx-vm32 ~]$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for linuxuser:
Sorry, user linuxuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as root on lx-vm32.company.com.
[linuxuser@lx-vm32 ~]$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for linuxuser:
Sorry, user linuxuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/ls' as root on lx-vm32.company.com.
[linuxuser@lx-vm32 ~]$ sudo su root
[sudo] password for linuxuser:
Sorry, user linuxuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/su root' as root on lx-vm32.company.com.
[linuxuser@lx-vm32 ~]$ sudo su -
[sudo] password for linuxuser:
Sorry, user linuxuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/su -' as root on lx-vm32.company.com.
[linuxuser@lx-vm32 ~]$ sudo su - root
Last login: Tue Mar  5 08:10:58 CST 2019 on pts/3
[root@lx-vm32 ~]#
```

Comment: as the `linuxuser` user, what does `sudo -l` show you?  It may be that this user is expressly limited to `sudo su - root`.

Comment: Add the `sudoers` file's contents to your question

Comment: Use below command to check what type of sudo access you have on host sed -n '/linuxuser/Ip'  /etc/sudoers  Check it as root

Comment: Does the sudoers file contain a line like `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
` ?

Comment: The system might be configured via LDAP
If set via LDAP, parsing of /etc/sudoers will be skipped

Comment: "Basically empty" or *actually* empty? Are you sure there's not a rule there that explicitly allows "/bin/su - root"?

Comment: @TimKennedy: yep - that appears to be it:

`User linuxuser may run the following commands on lx-vm33:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - root`
And without password!

Comment: That seems to be a strange way to limit privileged access.  Limiting a user in a way that they can undo the limits, or easily modify them seems like a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the issue isn't really with sudo, probably more of a security hardening issue. Since you have the root password, have a look at the stick-bits/permissions on the your `sudo` file.
On my unhardened machine:

```
[root@unhardened] ls -l /usr/bin/sudo 
-rwsr-xr-x root root /usr/bin/sudo
```

On my hardened machine:

```
[root@hardened] ls -l /usr/bin/sudo 
-rwxr-x--- root root /usr/bin/sudo
```

That may be the real culprit here. No sticky bit on sudo.

Comment: I don't even have the root password... Seems they have it set up to not need to know the root password, but at the same time not using the sudoers file.

`ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
---s--x--x. 1 root root 147392 Sep 25 01:02 /usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: That's not the sticky bit, it's the setuid bit (which makes `sudo` run as the file's owner -- root). Sticky would be indicated by a "t" or "T" in the last of the mode bit characters (instead of the "x" or "-" in the "other" section).

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be in the sudoers file in the /etc directory which contains system and user config files.

1) switch your user to root by doing " **su -** "

2) once your root type " **visudo** "

3) look for a title called '**User privilege specification**'

4) there should be something which says ' **root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL** ' this is the sudo configuration for the root user. if you do not see this then that explains the problem

5) under the 'User privilege specification' section type '**root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL** " ***KEEP IN MIND THAT THERE IS 4 SPACES INBETWEEN THE WORDS 'root' and the first 'ALL'.***

Comment: The user is not running as the root user. The `sudoers` line that you indicate would not come into effect here.

Comment: it may not be for the root user but it is definetly for the user 'linuxuser' as well as this he/she said the sudoers file is empty which also may explain the problem...